# MS Access database VBA counting populated cells in Excel worksheet column A is returning incorrect number of rows

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm importing an Excel worksheet's content into an Access database table and need to determine the number of rows in the Excel worksheet to import prior to triggering the process.   Using the traditional '.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row' I'm having returned the total 51 possible rows that could be populated rather than just the 2 or three with data.  I've tried using the WorksheetFunction.CountA method but don't really understand this and it doesn't seem to work for me.  Does anyone have any thoughts as to how I might effectively use the Excel 'CountA' function in Access VBA?  Many thanks.

```
    Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        XLApp.UserControl = True
        
        With XLApp
            XLApp.Visible = True
            Set xlwb = XLApp.ActiveWorkbook
            Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")
            
            With xlws
                RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            End With
```

Comment: A sample of your data, and your expected result are needed to answer this

Comment: Instead of having an area with a bunch of blank lines you might be able to use a table, which automatically expands with formulas filled in all calculated fields. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback...it's difficult to know what level of detail to include without appearing to ask for a solution to the whole project, rather than the one piece of errant code! :-D

I think the suggestion that the Excel workbook is the source of the issue could well be true...a macro within the workbook, designed to clear all cells, uses the cell .value = "", which is probably being read as 'space' rather than 'null'!?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have blank rows between the first and last rows. Note RowCount will include any header in row 1.

```vb
With XLApp
    .Visible = True
    Set xlwb = .ActiveWorkbook
    Set xlws = xlwb.Worksheets("Data")
    RowCount = .CountA(xlws.Range("A:A"))
End With
```

Comment: Many thanks for this solution.  Although the code runs fine the result is the same (a count of 51 rows).  As per my comment above I think my Excel workbook might be the issue - a macro within the workbook, designed to clear all cells, uses the cell .value = "", which is probably being read as 'space' rather than 'null'.  Not to worry, many thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know Access is already making a check similar to yours (blank/null cells/lines) during data imports from excel.  Therefore my approach to this problem would be;
importing all excel sheet into Access (with blank/undesired cells however Access imports it), and then apply a filter for the records I need in Access (probably via a query).